# Can a SQL Language Extension make REST API calls?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to create an extension to SQL server that calls external REST APIs. Before digging in further, I figured to ask the community if it's even possible. Are such extensions written in C# blocked from network access when using, for example, the WebClient class?

Comment: SQL Server isn’t a web application, why are you trying to use it to call REST APIs?

Comment: Extension... to SQL Server or to SSMS? Or are you talking about a CLR Stored Procedure?  But even so, what @AaronBertrand said.

Comment: Here's a link to what I am referring to since many won't be familiar. I wasn't until today. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/language-extensions-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: SQL Isn't a web application and I'm not trying to make it into one. But architecturally in our application it would be convenient to have SQL Server be able to invoke an API.

Comment: Its the wrong place to be doing that sort of thing, even though it is possible. Data operations need to be as fast as possible, calling something that takes real time and could hang, timeout, error etc from within your data storage is really not a good architectural decision.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not asking if it's right or wrong. I'm asking if it's possible. The docs don't list any limitations but I've not yet tried it.

Comment: I think the general consensus is: Yes, it's possible, but don't do it. Any delays you add to queries is increasing lock times, increasing block times and increasing your chances of deadlocks, generally worsening the responsiveness and reliability of your application. If RESTful calls can be performed asynchronously then they might as well be handled by external processes and not introduced into SQL Server itself.

Comment: It is possible, I did it before but I would not recommend it. Often the code breaks after updating .NET or the SQLServer because the same assembly cannot be load multiple times in the same process and SQLServer checks, whether the (references) assemblies you imported are the same that are loaded now. After an update they don't match anymore and you have to reimport the assembly to get it working again. No big deal but in production once in a while the code breaks.

Comment: @Christoph, are you saying that .Net Language Extensions in general are not recommended duoe to assembly management issues?

Comment: No, SQL-server has a list of safe assemblies, if you only reference them, you are fine (you get a warning when importing unsupported assemblies and I think you even have to explicitly allow them to be imported.). But network communication is (or at least was) not on that safe-list. I was performing a web method call using WCF.

Comment: @Christoph Do you have a pointer to the list of safe assemblies? I Googled but didn't find anything.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries?view=sql-server-ver15